# Consider adding .indexOn for Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a Firebase database as :

```
 "requested_rides" : {
"2016-10-04" : {
  "-KT9F_8DJHmKj33PW70w" : {
    "added_on" : 1475493385140,
    "code" : "AQZ66I4QP4",
    "date_of_ride" : "2016-10-04 AD 04:22 AM GMT+05:45",
    "day" : "Tomorrow",
    "dropoff_coordinate" : "27.6953541,85.2965062",
    "dropoff_location" : "Chunne Pakha",
    "fullname" : "bhaskarraj93@gmail.com",
    "offered_by" : "v1tENP2TaUVHaZFhSGuZ4M6cJJU2",
    "pickup_coordinate" : "27.716454540107783,85.32458111643793",
    "pickup_location" : "Kuber Plazza, Kathmandu 44600, Nepal",
    "seats" : "2",
    "share" : "578",
    "time" : "04:22 AM",
    "vechile_type" : "Bike"
  }
},
```

I have added rules to the database but I am getting this error

Consider adding `".indexOn": "code"` at /requested_rides/2016-11-23 to your security and Firebase rules for better performance

The rule that I defined is

```
"rules":{
    ".read":true,
    ".write":true,
    "requested_rides":{
        ".indexOn":"code"
    }
}
```

Comment: Likely answer below. But for a next question: please also add the code that triggers the error message. Without seeing that, it is hard to be certain.

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells to add the index to `/requested_rides/2016-11-23`. So that would be one level deeper:

```
"rules":{
    ".read":true,
    ".write":true,
    "requested_rides":{
        "2016-11-23": {
            ".indexOn":"code"
        }
    }
}
```

Or (more likely):

```
"rules":{
    ".read":true,
    ".write":true,
    "requested_rides":{
        "$date": {
            ".indexOn":"code"
        }
    }
}
```

This means that you can only query rides once you already *know* the date for the ride.

Answer (score 0):

you define indexOn in another way, try instead:

```
".indexOn":  ["code"]
```

Comment: Indexes can be defined as a singular property name *or* as an array of property names. Both are valid.